# SonarQube Java 3.9 - AnalysisException

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I've updated today to SonarQube Java plugin 3.9 and I'm getting the following error during analysis of my project.

The analysis works with Java plugin versions 3.8. It only fails against 3.9

```
00:02:10.233 Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '...java'
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:126)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:100)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:80)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:135)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:128)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:90)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:251)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:251)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
00:02:10.233    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:55)
00:02:10.234    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
00:02:10.234    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
00:02:10.234    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
00:02:10.234    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
00:02:10.234    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.execute(Unknown Source)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:275)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:153)
00:02:10.234    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:99)
00:02:10.234    ... 22 more
00:02:10.234 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
00:02:10.234    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:187)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.se.ProgramState.decreaseReference(ProgramState.java:200)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.se.ProgramState.cleanupDeadSymbols(ProgramState.java:244)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.cleanUpProgramState(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:224)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.handleBlockExit(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:232)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:175)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:130)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:215)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:41)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:89)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:72)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:65)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.model.InternalVisitorsBridge.visitFile(InternalVisitorsBridge.java:125)
00:02:10.234    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:117)
```

I'm using
Sonar-Server: 5.2
Maven-Plugin: 2.7.1

Any help to fix this issue?

Comment: In order to help you out, please share the analyzed source code (anonymized if necessary). Thanks.